# when i click JButton i want that game should start

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on a snake game project. I have three java files named:

- `Engine.java`
- `GameBoard.java`
- `Snake.java`

I have added two `JFrames` in this project. In the first frame are three buttons:

- `play`
- `rules`
- `exit`

When we click to `rules` button it opens `rules jframe` (it's working). When we click `play` button it should run the snake game. Please suggest me what should i do when i click `play` button to actually starts the game.

This is the code i copied in `play` button `actionPerformed` method:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SnakeGame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GameBoard.MAP_SIZE * GameBoard.TILE_SIZE, GameBoard.MAP_SIZE * GameBoard.TILE_SIZE));
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        new Engine(canvas).startGame();
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @ankush-pruthi please use edit button, add `Engine` code and write more about your problem - what do you expect? what do you try? etc.

Comment: Don't use a Canvas that is an AWT component. In a Swing program you would use a JPanel.

Comment: @rebeliagamer : in this i am facing a problem like when i click play button gameboard is appearing o the screen 'snake'and 'fruit' also appearing , but problem is snake is not moving . Originally in this project only three classes were there , in order to improve GUI i have added two JFrames from my side. One Jframe contain three button         and out of them there is a 'play' button, i want when play button get clicked the game should start , but problem i am facing is gameboard appearing o the screen but snake is ot moving and also output is hangig too

Comment: @camickr this method is not available with JPanel canvas.createBufferStrategy(2); .. is there any alternate method that can i use with JPael for the same purposes.

Comment: @AnkushPruthi, you don't need to use a BufferStrategy. Swing is double buffered by default.

Answer (score 1):

Add an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to your "play" button that calls the appropriate start method.

Comment: i have already added ActionListener to play button.. Problem i am facing is when i click play button the gameboard is appearing but snake is not moving i.e snake is motionless..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if I understand your question correctly: Your Snake.java is a GUI?
If so, then make an object of your GUI "Snake", when you click on the play-button:

```
JButton play = new JButton("play");

play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Snake play = new Snake();
        }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson no on java

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: of course you are right. That was android source code. I edited the code.

Comment: @tharos ohh and now i am adding some things in it

Comment: is there a start method, which leads your snake to move?

Comment: :yes there is a startGame() method in Engine.java class.

Comment: ok, then call the startGame() methode in the constructor of your Snake class

Comment: Snake class doesn't have any main function or any contructor..in this project Engine class have main method

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : Can i mail you my project so that u can see/observe where i am lacking in this project.