# how to open one Jframe from main method call

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have downloaded a snake game project in java and try to modify it. Initially the project contains three java files 
i.e "`Engine.jav`a" , "`Snake.java`", "`GameBoard.java`". And `Engine.java` have  the `main()` method, and when i run this Engine.java class game starts running.

To improve the user iteractivity towards the project i have created two JFrames :"`PlayGame.java`", `Rules.java`

Now this project having five java classes -

```
Engine.java(containing main() method) 
Snake.java
GameBoard.java
PlayGame.java(is a JFrame)
Rules.java(is a JFrame)

PlayGame.java have three buttons

Play - i want when play button get clicked snake game start/run.
Rules - when clicked Rules.java Jframe should be opened 
Exit - exits the application
```

Now what i want is at first "`PlayGame.java`" JFrame should appear(and this is appearing as the main output of the game project) and throw this game should start i.e when i click play button from `PlayGame JFrame` game should start
The problem i am facing is when i click `play` button then `gamescreen` appears on the window but `snake is not moving`.

Here is the code that i have included in `actionPerformed()` method of `Play button`

```
        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("SnakeGame");
    frame.setVisible(true); 
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
            canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GameBoard.MAP_SIZE * GameBoard.TILE_SIZE, GameBoard.MAP_SIZE * GameBoard.TILE_SIZE));
            frame.getContentPane().add(canvas); 
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            new Engine(canvas).startGame();
}
```

and also i am showing code of `startGame()` method which is in `Engine.java` class

```
public void startGame() {
    canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)canvas.getBufferStrategy().getDrawGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    long start = 0L;
    long sleepDuration = 0L;
    while(true) {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        update();
        render(g);

        canvas.getBufferStrategy().show();

        g.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        sleepDuration = (1500L / UPDATES_PER_SECOND) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);

        if(sleepDuration > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepDuration);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here also i am attaching the Engine.java class and PlayGame.java in my question for better understandig of problem

> Engine.java

```
package org.psnbtech;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.psnbtech.GameBoard.TileType;
import org.psnbtech.Snake.Direction;


public class Engine extends KeyAdapter {

    private static final int UPDATES_PER_SECOND = 15;

    private static final Font FONT_SMALL = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);

    private static final Font FONT_LARGE = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40);

    public Canvas canvas;

    public GameBoard board;

    public Snake snake;

    public int score;

    public boolean gameOver;


    public Engine(Canvas canvas) {
                this.canvas = canvas;
            this.board = new GameBoard();
        this.snake = new Snake(board);

        resetGame();

        canvas.addKeyListener(this);
                //new Engine(canvas).startGame();
    }


    public void startGame() {
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)canvas.getBufferStrategy().getDrawGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        long start = 0L;
        long sleepDuration = 0L;
        while(true) {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            update();
            render(g);

            canvas.getBufferStrategy().show();

            g.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

            sleepDuration = (1500L / UPDATES_PER_SECOND) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);

            if(sleepDuration > 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepDuration);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        if(gameOver || !canvas.isFocusOwner()) {
            return;
        }
        TileType snakeTile = snake.updateSnake();
        if(snakeTile == null || snakeTile.equals(TileType.SNAKE)) {
            gameOver = true;
        } else if(snakeTile.equals(TileType.FRUIT)) {
            score += 10;
            spawnFruit();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        board.draw(g);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        if(gameOver) {
            g.setFont(FONT_LARGE);
            String message = new String("Your Score: " + score);
            g.drawString(message, canvas.getWidth() / 2 - (g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(message) / 2), 250);

            g.setFont(FONT_SMALL);
            message = new String("Press Enter to Restart the Game");
            g.drawString(message, canvas.getWidth() / 2 - (g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(message) / 2), 350);
        } else {
            g.setFont(FONT_SMALL);
            g.drawString("Score:" + score, 10, 20);
        }
    }

    public void resetGame() {
        board.resetBoard();
        snake.resetSnake();
        score = 0;
        gameOver = false;
        spawnFruit();
    }

    public void spawnFruit() {
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * ((GameBoard.MAP_SIZE * GameBoard.MAP_SIZE) - snake.getSnakeLength())); // if '*' replace by '/' then only one fruit is there for snake

        int emptyFound = 0;
        int index = 0;
        while(emptyFound < random) {
            index++;
            if(board.getTile(index % GameBoard.MAP_SIZE, index / GameBoard.MAP_SIZE).equals(TileType.EMPTY)) { // if '/' replaced by '*' then nothing displays on the board 
                emptyFound++;
            }
        }
        board.setTile(index % GameBoard.MAP_SIZE, index / GameBoard.MAP_SIZE, TileType.FRUIT); // it also show nothing when replacing '/' by '/' 
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)||(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)) {
            snake.setDirection(Direction.UP);
        }
        if((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)||(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
            snake.setDirection(Direction.DOWN);
        }
        if((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)||(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
            snake.setDirection(Direction.LEFT);
        }
        if((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)||(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)) {
            snake.setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && gameOver) {
            resetGame();
        }
    }

         public static void main(String[] args)  {
        new PlayGame().setVisible(true);

        /**JFrame frame = new JFrame("SnakeGame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GameBoard.MAP_SIZE * GameBoard.TILE_SIZE, GameBoard.MAP_SIZE * GameBoard.TILE_SIZE));

        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

        new Engine(canvas).startGame();*/


             }        
}
```

> PlayGame.java

```
package org.psnbtech;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class PlayGame extends javax.swing.JFrame  {



   public PlayGame() {

        initComponents();      
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/org/psnbtech/GUID-4ED364DF-2D44-40F5-9F05-31D451F15EF1-low.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Rules");
        jButton2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(89, 39));
        jButton2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(89, 39));
        jButton2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(89, 41));
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/org/psnbtech/exit (1).png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("Exit");
        jButton3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(89, 41));
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/org/psnbtech/play.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Play");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(277, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27))))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(75, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit(0);        
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        this.dispose();
        new Rules().setVisible(true);

    }                                        



    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("SnakeGame");
        frame.setVisible(true); 
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
                canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GameBoard.MAP_SIZE * GameBoard.TILE_SIZE, GameBoard.MAP_SIZE * GameBoard.TILE_SIZE));
                //canvas.addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);
                frame.getContentPane().add(canvas); 
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                new Engine(canvas).startGame();
    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [when i click JButton i want that game should start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956965/when-i-click-jbutton-i-want-that-game-should-start)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taht happens because you call

```
new PlayGame().setVisible(true);
```

and

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Show just the first frame and on button click the second.

The recommended approach is to use just one frame always but multiple panels 1. where game is rendered and 2. options pane. Swap them e.g. by using `CardLayout`.

Also don't use `Canvas` use `JPanel` instead overriding `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: thats ok. now further tell me if i want to display the gameframe on screen when play button is clicked. for this purpose what code i have to add in actionPerformed() method of play button ..Is the same code i.e present in main() method of Engine.java class or else

Comment: It could be the same code. Or if you want to reuse frame (create once) then you can keep a fererence to the frame and just make it visible on click

Comment: exactly i am using the same code in actionPerformed() method but problem encountered is that snake is not moving and also the gameframe output is hanging

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwing:

```
JFrameAdd ja = new JFrameAdd();
ja.setVisible(true);
ja.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Hope it will help!